# ForEach Directory Lookup and InputObject Powershell

Tags: powershell

Can someone help me and point out why my script isn't looping through my server list and not inserting all the data to my sql table?

```
$SQLserverDB = @()
$SQLserverDB = get-content "D:\Temp\servers.txt" 
foreach ($SQLserver in $SQLserverDB) { 
    $server = New-Object Microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server($SQLserver)

    Write-Host "--Server List:"$server"---" -ForegroundColor Yellow 

    foreach ($db in $Server.Databases) {
        $dbobj = New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
                Instance_Name       = $db.Parent  
                Database_Name       = $db.Name    
                Database_ID         = $db.id 
                Active              = $db.Status
                DateStamp           = $db.CreateDate  
                Owner               = $db.Owner
                Compatibility_Level = $db.compatibilitylevel
                Recovery_Model      = $db.recoverymodel
                DB_Size_MB          = [Math]::round($db.size, 2)
            }
        )
    }
}

$dt = Out-DbaDataTable -InputObject $dbobj

Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance localhost -DatabaseName DBA_Central -SchemaName dbo -TableName database_masters2 -InputData $dt
```

Comment: The problem is the $dt variable is being set outside of your foreach loop. The $dbobj variable is being overwritten each time an element of the loop is processed. If you want to preserve all values of $dbobj, you need to store that into $dt within the loop. If you want to write to the sql data table after each database is evaluated, then you will also need to move the write-sqltabledata line inside of the loop as well.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What makes you think that the loop itself is not run?

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thanks so much, I will give this a try.

Comment: @NicoHaase I know the loop is running but wasn't sure why it was only inserting the first server in my list.  I've also tried using foreach-object and got the same results.